# Replace or overwrite time value in php

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the time value how to overwrite or replace in php

```
    "users": [
        {
            "1": {
                "time": null
            }
        }
    ]
}';`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep that structure, you could iterate through your users array.

```
function replaceTimeValueForUserWithId($users, $id) {
    // iterate through your users array
    foreach($users['users'] as &$user) {
        if (isset($user[$id])) {
            $user[$id]['time'] = date("Y-m-d");
        }
    }
    return $users;
}

$json = '
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "1": {
                    "time": null
                }
            },
            {
                "2": {
                    "time": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
';

// convert the json to a php array
$users = json_decode($json, true);
$users = replaceTimeValueForUserWithId($users, 2);

// re-encode the php array to json
echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. is it possible to update time value based on the key. eg  $json = '
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "1": {
                    "time": null
                }
            }, {
                "2": {
                    "time": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
'; if I want to update the time value for the key "2"

Comment: I edited my answer. Usually, you should google for basics like this.